# Why does my player stop moving forward randomly at Z = 990

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity

I have a game where my player need to move forward without stopping, sometimes he stop moving at Z = 990 and if i move him on editor a little bit he start moving again.

EX: https://youtu.be/A0FB595AdHI

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    if(forwardSpeed < maxSpeed)
    {
        forwardSpeed += Time.deltaTime * speedIncrementor;
    }

    rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, rb.velocity.y, forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (forwardSpeed > maxSpeed)
    {
        forwardSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: The next platform is higher than the previous one, so you're hitting an edge? I'm guessing this because it seems to be JUST at the edge of the new platform (as seen when the previous platform is removed)

Comment: No, the 2nd platform spawn at the end of the 1st and they are on the same high, i do some research and can be from the velocity but i dont know

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong in the code you supplied. Except, perhaps, that using Time.deltaTime in FixedUpdate seems a bit weird.

Comment: Yeah Maakep is right: you should use [Time.fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

Comment: Ok, i think i find the reason, if the platform are on the same height is a chance to player get stack on the next one so i lowered the height with -0.1, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Time.deltaTime is NOT the physics timestep.

Time.deltatime (duration of last frame) should only be used in once per frame calls e.g. Update() calls.

Time.fixedDeltaTime should only be used in FixedUpdate(), since it the sample time of the physics loop

If this does not fix the issue u can simply use the logic of restarting the terrain logic . That means it will start start running from the point your game object start moving